# Unitary operators with the same inner product as vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, clifford-algebras, inner-product, spinor

Suppose we have a set of real unit vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We can always find a set of unitary operators $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^N$ (for $N$ that is possibly much larger than $n$) such that the dimension-normalized Hilbert-Schmidt inner product $\langle U_i,U_j \rangle$ is the same as the vector inner product $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle$.

This is due to the existence of Weyl-Brauer operators (also known as generators of Clifford algebra). Let us very quickly see this. For every $n$ there exist unitary operators $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$ such that $\sigma_i^2 = I$ and such that they pairwise anticommute $\sigma_i\sigma_j = -\sigma_j\sigma_i$ for all $i\neq j$. Now if we let $U_i = \sum_{j=1}^n v_{ij} \sigma_j$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$, then the operators $U_i$ have the properties mentioned above. Note that we used notation $v_i = (v_{i1},\ldots,v_{in})$.

My question is does this also hold for complex vectors? If $v_i$s are unit vectors from a complex Euclidean space $\mathbb{C}^n$, can we find unitaries (possibly in a larger but finite dimensional space) such that the pairwise inner product of unitaries is the same as the inner product of the vectors? Is there some theorem that maybe preventing us from having this hold for complex Euclidean spaces?

I would appreciate any references in the literature studying similar problems. For example here I am interested in norm induced from the inner product on the Euclidean space. But people may have studied this for other norms and knowing that could still be of interest to me.

Comment: Thanks for this remark. The problem with the approach you suggested is that unitary operators do not form a vector space. In particular linear combinations of unitary operators are not necessarily unitary. This is one reason why Weyl-Brauer construction is necessary.